# How to split a text file that contains colons separated data

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a project using VB, and I'm trying to import a text file that has line of the following format:
`Email:Password`

I have managed to read line by line individually and can make my program show an individual line such as, `MessageBox.Show(line(2))`

I have also managed to split this text file but it only fills array `Seperate(0)` and `Seperate(1)`

But when I call `Seperate(0)` it will display all the Emails, and when I call `Seperate(1)` it displays all the passwords.

I want to split line by line, so I could place the values in two different textboxes (which require only 1 email and password).

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Read [ask] and take the [tour].  We cannot tell you what is wrong with your code without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could start first by create a Structure that represent 1 line in your file (Email:Password), this is just a custom data type

```
Structure Account
    Public Email As String
    Public Pasword As String
End Structure
```

Then create a Function that encapsulate the parsing of email and password from your file, this function just takes the file path and return all the emails and passwords it found on the file.

It also handles the duplicates, so it adds only unique ones.

```
Function GetAccounts(filePath As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    'We need to a Dictionary data structure, so that we can easily avoid returning duplicates (if the file contains duplicates)
    Dim allaccounts As New Dictionary(Of String, String) 'Create the dictionary of accounts in the file (we will return this object)
    Dim fileInf As New FileInfo(filePath)
    fileInf.Refresh()
    If fileInf.Exists = True Then 'If file is found
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(fileInf.FullName) 'Load your file here
        Dim filecontent As String = sr.ReadToEnd 'Read the file content (Email:Password Lines)
        sr.Close() 'Close the stream on the file

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(filecontent) = False Then 'Making sure that the file is not empty
            If InStr(filecontent, Chr(10)) <> 0 Then 'If the file has multiple lines, then we will need to loop through the lines
                Dim tmpSP() As String = filecontent.Split(Chr(10)) 'split the file content by lines and put the results in an array
                For i As Integer = 0 To tmpSP.Count - 1
                    'This will make sure that we read the line from the file without any TAB,NewLine characters..etc (clean line)
                    Dim tmp As String = tmpSP(i).Replace(Chr(13), "").Replace(Chr(11), "").Replace(Chr(9), "").Trim
                    If InStr(tmp, ":") <> 0 Then 'make sure that this line is in valid format (email:password)
                        Dim pair() As String = tmp.Split(":")
                        If IsNothing(pair) = False Then
                            If pair.Length = 2 Then
                                If allaccounts.ContainsKey(pair(0).ToLower) = False Then 'Email will be the Key, password will be the Value
                                    allaccounts.Add(pair(0).ToLower, pair(1).ToLower)
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Else 'If the file has only 1 line (1 email:password pair) then we take it
                If InStr(filecontent, ":") <> 0 Then 'making sure that this lonely line is in the correct (email:password format)
                    Dim tmp As String = filecontent.Replace(Chr(13), "").Replace(Chr(11), "").Replace(Chr(9), "").Trim
                    Dim pair() As String = tmp.Split(":")
                    If IsNothing(pair) = False Then
                        If pair.Length = 2 Then
                            If allaccounts.ContainsKey(pair(0).ToLower) = False Then 'Email will be the Key, password will be the Value
                                allaccounts.Add(pair(0).ToLower, pair(1).ToLower)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return allaccounts
End Function
```

To use this function, lets say you want to parse that file in a `button1.Click()`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim foundaccounts As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    ofd.Filter = "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt"
    If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        foundaccounts = GetAccounts(ofd.FileName)
        'You can now loop throught the list of returned emails:password in the file
        'Inside the below `For Each` & `Next` you can write Textbox1.Text = currentEmail, but not outside this below block
        For Each keyval As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In foundaccounts
            Dim currentEmail As String = keyval.Key
            Dim currentPassword As String = keyval.Value
            Textbox1.Text = currentEmail
            Textbox2.Text = currentPassword
        Next        
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried to comment as much as I can, and I hope this answers your questions.

Let me know if it doesn't or if there is anything unclear. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for that. In this line : "Dim sr As New StreamReader(fileInf.FullName) 'Load your file here" , am I supposed to change anything? it doesn't bring up any errors.

Also, how do I place the values in the textboxes ? When I try to set Textbox1.Text = currentEmail , it says currentEmail isn't declared.

Sorry if I sound like an Idiot. I just started VB like a week ago.

Comment: @DenisFarrugia No you don't need to change anything here `Dim sr As New StreamReader(fileInf.FullName)` the file path will automatically be set to whatever file path you choose when you pick your file from the dialog box that will popup. As long as you have Button1 on your form, this code will work right away. The reason you are getting `not declared` error is because you are writing `Textbox1.Text=currentEmail` outside the `For Each` and `Next` . if your file has only 1 line of Email:Password, then see the change I made to the code. Also if it worked, dont forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: @DenisFarrugia if your file contain many lines of Email:Password then it is not logical to set them all in the textbox, because TextBox should contain 1 email and its password. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to import a text file with let's say like 10 accounts of mine. Then, I want to split the file and put 1 line at a time, in two textboxes. TextBox1 and TextBox2. Once a button is pressed I want it to do a loop, for let's say 15 times, by going from line 1 to line 10, doing the Send function and repeating until it meets the condition. Is it possible?

Comment: @DenisFarrugia I suggest that you open another question and be really detailed about what you need. It will resolve your problem much faster

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934820/issue-with-splitting-text-file?noredirect=1#comment82839615_47934820